# Bootstrap 4.3 Tab not switching from the first tab

Tags: html, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I've incorporated bootstrap tabs into my web app following the documentation on the bootstrap [website.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navs/#tabshow)

I've so far managed to get the first tab fade animation to play and show the the other two tabs don't seem to work and I'm quite stumped as to why.

```
<div id="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li id="dashboardTab" class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" id="dashboard-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#dashboard" role="tab" aria-controls="dashboard" aria-selected="true">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li id="usersTab" class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="userCreate-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#userCreate" role="tab" aria-controls="userCreate" aria-selected="false">Users<span onclick="onCloseTabButtonClick(0)">X</span></a>
                </li>
                <li id="wholesalerTab" class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="wholesalerCreate-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#wholesalerCreate" role="tab" aria-controls="wholesalerCreate" aria-selected="false">Wholesalers<span onclick="onCloseTabButtonClick(1)">X</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="dashboard" class="tab-pane fade show active" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="dashboard-tab">
                    <h3>Dash Tab</h3>
                    <iframe class="iframe-size" id="dashboardHolder" src="Dashboard.aspx" />
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="userCreate" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="userCreate-tab">
                    <h3>User Tab</h3>
                    <iframe class="iframe-size" src="UserCreate.aspx" />
                </div>
                <div id="wholesalerCreate" class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="wholesalerCreate-tab">
                    <h3>Wholesaler Tab</h3>
                    <iframe class="iframe-size" src="WholsalerCreate.aspx" />
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Alot of similar questions I've read show that the error is simply not importing the Jquery and the bootstrap js files.

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I have got this in my header and do believe it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tabs do not work well with Iframes. So remove them. It is also a better user experience.

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="dashboard" class="tab-pane fade show active" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="dashboard-tab">
        <h3>Dash Tab</h3>
        <div class="iframe-size">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="userCreate" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="userCreate-tab">
        <h3>User Tab</h3>
        <div class="iframe-size">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wholesalerCreate" class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="wholesalerCreate-tab">
        <h3>Wholesaler Tab</h3>
        <div class="iframe-size">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Removing the Iframes worked, thank you. What would you suggest I use instead ? Each page needs to be pulled through under the tab, hence the iframes

Comment: You can just simply put the contents of those pages inside the tabs.